# Uploading files automatically from Google Cloud to Big Query

Tags: bigdata, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

How to automate the process of uploading .CSV files from Google Cloud onto Big Query.

Comment: You should add to your question what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage provides [access and storage log files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs) in CSV formats which can be directly imported into BigQuery for analysis. In order to access these logs, you must [set up log delivery and enable logging](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs#delivery). The schemas are available online, in JSON format, for both the storage access logs and [storage bucket data](http://storage.googleapis.com/pub/cloud_storage_storage_schema_v0.json). More information is available in the [Cloud Storage access logs and storage data documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs).

In order to load storage and access logs into BigQuery from the command line, use a command such as:

```
bq load --schema=cloud_storage_usage_schema.json my_dataset.usage_2012_06_18_v0 gs://my_logs/bucket_usage_2012_06_18_14_v0
```

Comment: thanks Pentium10 . But is there a way to automatically upload a .CSV dataset from Cloud storage onto BigQuery. Kindly let me know. It will be very much appreciated

Comment: @badarinarayan You need to create some sort of script that runs the import.

Comment: you mean create a appscript  @Pentium10

Comment: Checkout the [BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries) hat you can use to access the Google BigQuery API in different languages.

Comment: Thanks @Pentium10,  am grateful to you. kindly keep in touch.

Comment: I tried the .NET library for getting the objects from Cloud Storage. But how to get the objects from buckets to load onto Big Query. I am finding it difficult. Can anyone please help  @Pentium10